# How to create test cases in Drupal 8 to test rest api

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new in Drupal 8 and I want to know how to create test cases in Drupal 8 to test Rest API. I couldn't find any solution on how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use behat https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalextension and test a petition to your endpoint then review the contents contain the field titles that you need.